# Converter formato de data para outro

Tags: javascript, node.js

Gostaria de converter este formato de data:

`Wed Jul 20 2016 17:55:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)`

para este formato:

`2016-07-20T14:55:00.000-03:00`

Comment: O primeiro formato que tens é String ou é um Objeto data?

Comment: É uma string @Sergio

Comment: Isso parece `new Date('Wed Jul 20 2016 17:55:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)').toISOString();` mas com `-03:00` no fim :/ Onde precisas de usar essa string?

Comment: Irei dar um exemplo do meu problema: Possuo uma string `A data de hoje é date`. E eu realizo um replace, e onde há a palavra `date` eu substituo por `2016-07-20T14:55:00.000-03:00`. Até ai tudo bem, porém, quando realizo um `console.log`, ele mostra: `A data de hoje é Wed Jul 20 2016 17:55:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)`. Não entendi na verdade pq se converteu sozinho para esse formato, mas queria converter de volta.

Comment: @Sergio, entendeu ?